# Firebase presence: onDisconnect make a transaction

Tags: javascript, firebase

Inside the auth callback we add a captain to the list as we have a new player:

```
var cptns = new Firebase("http://allure.firebaseio.com/cptns");


cptns.transaction(function(current_value) {return current_value + 1;
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
$('#captains').text(snapshot.val());
});
```

My goal is to decrease current_value by 1 when player/captain leaves the page. I did try what docs suggested with no luck, as when I log out it does not alert ("not connected")

```
var connectedRef = new Firebase('http://allure.firebaseio.com/.info/connected');
connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    alert('connected');
  } else {
    alert('not connected');
  }
});
```

This didn't work either:

```
     // Get a reference to my own presence status.
     var connectedRef = new Firebase("http://presence.allure.firebaseio.com/.info/connected");
      connectedRef.on("value", function(isOnline) {
        if (!isOnline.val()) {
          cptns.transaction(function(current_value) {return current_value -1;
    }, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
    $('#captains').text(snapshot.val());
    });

    alert("removed 1");


        } 

else{    alert("all good do nothing");

}
      });
```

what am I missing? TIA

(thanks firebase for the amazing platform you've built ! )

Comment: Note that .info/connected is only useful for knowing if a connection has been lost while the app is still open. If you close the window / navigate away, we have no way of running javascript. We run the onDisconnect operations server-side to get around this (which is why you can't run a transaction OnDisconnect, because transactions require client-side code to be run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, as far as I understand, use a transaction on disconnect. Also, `.info/connected` monitors the individual client's connection to Firebase, not other users' connections.

The good news is presence is very straightforward, and assuming that each "team" is not going to have dozens of thousands of users, you don't really need the transaction. Instead, you can:

- maintain a list of members
- set a presence field on each member onDisconnect:  `firebaseRef.child('member/status').onDisconnect().set('offline')`
- count the members on the client (rather trivial)

If you provide some more details on the client structure (how teams are structured, how many players in a team, at al) then I can provide more concrete examples.

Comment: gracias Kato, I was acting lazy and hopin' for a six lines solution, the plan you suggest works. Your answers (at least firebase related) on SO are always helpful :)

Comment: Thanks! It's good to feel useful. Or usable. Or of any use. Btw, it's probably not much more than 6 lines once you get the structure right. It takes a little paradigm shift, but the nosql can be quite straightforward once you get the hang of it.